# Insert multiple row with condition checking on other table.. only single query

Tags: php, mysql, multirow

**Table1: usermaster**

```
uid uname
1    abc
2    xyz
3    pqr
4    def
```

**Table2: transactionmaster**

```
tid uid amount type
1    1  100    1
2    2  500    1
2    2  500    2
3    1  350    1
3    1  150    2
```

**type in transaction table:**

```
1 for capital
2 for interest(5% of total capital)
```

Now, I want to calculate the `interest` of capital amount and ad interest of capital values 5% every month.
Query should be passed which is : *add interest entry in `transactionmaster` table automatically for both users who have capital*.

Result should like this in `transactionmaster` table.

```
tid uid amount type
1    1  100    1
2    2  500    1
3    1  600    1
4    1  35     2
5    2  25     2
```

Here `interest` also count automatically 5%.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick :

```
INSERT INTO transactionmaster (uid, amount, type)
SELECT uid, ((SUM(amount) / 100) * 5), 2
FROM transactionmaster
WHERE type = 1 
GROUP BY uid
```

I assumed that the `tid` field is an autoicrement

---

Edit: 
The query above is a oneshot. ie it will systematically create "type 2" entries for all uid that have "type 1". In other words, if you use it several times you'll end up with duplicates "type 2" entries.

If you want to INSERT "type 2" rows for only "type 1" that don't have "type 2" rows yet, you can do this :

```
INSERT INTO transactionmaster (uid, amount, type)
SELECT t1.uid, ((SUM(t1.amount) / 100) * 5), 2
FROM transactionmaster t1 
LEFT JOIN transactionmaster t2 ON t1.uid=t2.uid AND t1.type=1 AND t2.type=2 
WHERE t2.tid IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.uid
```

---

Edit 2 to answer your comment.

Suppose you create an intrustmaster table having this structure :

```
loweramt | higheramt | perc
---------------------------
100      | 199       | 5
200      | 399       | 4
```

The oneshot query will become this :

```
INSERT INTO transactionmaster (uid, amount, type)
SELECT T.uid, ((totamt /100) * i.perc), 2
FROM 
(
    SELECT uid, (SUM(amount) / 100) as totamt
    FROM transactionmaster
    WHERE type = 1 
    GROUP BY uid
) T
INNER JOIN intrustmaster I
  ON t.totamt BETWEEN i.loweramt AND i.higheramt
```

Comment: let me suggest one thing here if intrust is different for every stage then how it possible, suppose i make one table intrustmaster and there is 3 slab, 100-200 intrust is 5%, 200-400 intrust is 4% and 500-1000 5% then what changes needed?

Comment: 100-200 and 200-400 being the total amount for a uid?

Comment: yes, total amount for uid, intrustmaster fields (id,min,max,intrust_rate). data(1,100,200,5)(2,201,400,4)(3,401,500,5)

Comment: answered but chitchatting like this is not a proper way to Q&A on SO. So if you have further questions, edit your answer and add details, or create a new question with more specific elements.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result automatically on every month you need to schedule your SQL query using MySQL events.

Here is the reference
1) http://www.infotuts.com/schedule-sql-query-using-phpmyadmin-mysql-events/

Get the Sum of capital from transactionmaster

```
select sum(amount) from transactionmaster where uid = 13 and type=1
```

Now get count the interest

```
select sum(amount) * (5 / 100)  as interest from transactionmaster where uid=13 and type=1
```

simple!